# About the order of an automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-group

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}\times \ldots\times\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ be a direct sum of $m>1$ cyclic groups of order $p^n$. Suppose you have an automorphism $\alpha$ acting irreducibly on $\Omega_1(G)$, on $\Omega_2(G)/\Omega_1(G)$, etc... May we say that the order of $\alpha$ tends to infinity with $n\to\infty$?

**Addendum**

I forgot the condition $m>1$, since clearly this is not true for $m=1$.

Comment: I presume that $\Omega_i(G)$ denotes the set of $p^i$-torsion elements of $G$?

Comment: @CardboardBox Yes, that should be standard terminology

Comment: I don't think so. For example, with $m=2$, the element $\left(\begin{array}{rr}-1&-1\\1&0\end{array}\right)$ has order $3$ and I think it satisfies your conditions on irreducible action for all $n$  when $p \ne 3$.

Comment: Sorry, the action in my example is irreducible only when $p \equiv 2 \bmod 3$. It's easy to construct similar examples for larger $m$.